# yii add validation in search at admim page

Tags: php, yii

i have controler for coba2. on function actionAdmin i'll add validation on search because when integer is searched by non integer it'll give SQL error

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "a" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "yii_user" "t" WHERE id_user='a' ^. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "yii_user" "t" WHERE id_user=:ycp0
```

here is my function to call validate function on my model

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new coba2('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['coba2']))
                $model->attributes=$_GET['coba2'];

            if($model->validate()){
                $this->render('admin',array(
                        'model'=>$model,
                ));
            } else{
                $model->unsetAttributes();
                $this->render('admin',array(
                        'model'=>$model,
                ));
            }
}
```

and here is rules in my model

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('username, password, salt, date_create, date_update, date_birth', 'required'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                    array('id_user', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true, 'on'=>'search'),
        array('id_user, username, password, salt, date_create, date_update, date_birth', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

sorry my English is bad, but i need help.
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you've got id_user as an `'integerOnly'=>true, 'on'=>'search'`, try adding the following rule to your model, this will force id_user to be numerical in all scenarios, not just 'search':

```
array('id_user', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
```